# Why is my generated QR code distorted when displaying it in a PDF with dompdf in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, dompdf

I am trying to display a generated QR code inside my generated PDF but for some reason it's really distorted. Even when I specify the dimensions inside the element or as a class with CSS it does not match those dimensions.

My entire PDF page:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
        <title>Kaart</title>
        <style>
            body{
                margin: 0;
                white-space: nowrap;
            }
            .card{
                border:1px solid black;
                height: 1102px;
                position: relative;
                width: 1575px;
            }

            .card .left{
                width: 50%;
                border-right: 1px solid black;
                height: 100%;
                position: relative;
                display: inline-block;
            }

            .card .right{
                width: 50%;
                height: 100%;
                position: relative;
                display: inline-block;
            }

            .card .right .text{
                position: relative;
                top: 50%;
                left: 50%;
                transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
                text-align: center;
                white-space: normal;
                width: 80%;
            }

            .card .left img{
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
            }

            .text .top{
                font-size: 50px;
            }

            .text .bottom{
                font-size: 30px;
            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    @foreach($cards as $key => $card)
        <div class="card">
            <div class="left">
                <img src="{{ $card['card_image'] }}">
            </div>
            <div class="right">
                <div class="text">
                    <div class="top">
                        <p>{!! nl2br($card['message']) !!}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="bottom">
                        <p>Scan de QR-code of ga naar {{ $card['donate_url'] }} om te doneren aan een goed doel naar keuze.</p>
                        <div class="qr-wrap">
                            <img class="qr" src="data:image/png;base64,{{ base64_encode($card['qr_code']) }}" />
                        </div>
                        <p>Waarde: <b>{{ $card['wallet_amount'] }}</b></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        @if(($key + 1) !== $total)
            <div class="page-break"></div>
        @endif
    @endforeach
    </body>
</html>
```

In my controller I specify the qr data as:  `'qr_code' => QrCode::size(300)->generate(route('donate', ['hash' => $hash], true)),`

And then load the view like this:

```
$customPaper = array(0,0,626.50,1181.25);
$file = $pdf->loadView('admin.order.card', $data)->setPaper($customPaper, 'landscape')->setOptions(['dpi' => '200']);
```

I've tried directly generating the QR inside the blade file but this has the same effect. Also I've tried to add width and height parameters directly in the image tag but no effect.

This is what it looks like:

[image]

I've also tried adding it inside a wrapper:

```
   .qr-wrap{
                position: relative;
                width: 300px;
                height: 300px;
            }
            .qr{
                height: 100%;
                width: 100%;
                /*width: 3000px;*/
                /*height: 100px;*/
            }
```

Comment: @KJ It is a QR code, I just noticed if I set the width to 300px and the height to 8px it looks like a QR and is scannable with my phone. Why these weird dimensions? The output is not 8px but if I for example use 5px height, the height is halved. Also the text below it is inside the QR so the image is not treated as a block element.

Comment: There's lots you can do to narrow the problem down here. What does it look like if you view that HTML directly in a browser? What does the PNG look like if you save `$card['qr_code']` to a file? What happens if you substitute a different image in that img tag? What happens if you put nothing but the QR code image into the template, removing all other HTML and CSS? Test a few things on those lines, and eventually you'll either spot the problem, or have a [mre] to show us (the current code is not, because we don't know have the value of `$card['qr_code']`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What QR Code generator do you use? Maybe there is an second size option?

This works for me:

```
<img alt="QR Code" src="data:image/png;base64, {!!
      base64_encode(\SimpleSoftwareIO\QrCode\Facades\QrCode::format('png')
      ->size(60)->generate($qr_code)) !!} ">
```

Also you could try to set background-colors. It helps to debug the different HTML elements.

Comment: I found out the QR code was an SVG and using format was too much work because I am testing it locally without the imagick extension installed. So instead of the SimpleSoftwareIO plugin I used: https://github.com/chillerlan/php-qrcode and use the php gdimage library to generate it as a png and this fixed everything!